# Minimum Number of Operations needed

Tags: c, algorithm, string, pattern-matching

I have a problem, suppose I have a given string: "best", the target string is suppose: "beast". Then I have to determine the number of operations to convert the given string to the target string, however the operations allowed are: 
1. add a character to string.
2. delete a character.
3. swap two char positions. (should be used wisely, we have only one chance to swap.)

In above case it is 1.
How do we solve such kind of problem, and what kind of problem is it?
I am a newbie learner.

Comment: This has the distinct aroma of homework.

Answer (score 3):

One widely-used measure of this kind of thing is called the Levenshtein distance.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

The WP page also mentions/links to other similar concepts. It is essentially a metric of the number of edits needed to turn one word into another.

Answer (score 1):

[Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)